# Unable to see the stored data in the back end(Parse.com)

Tags: java, android, xml, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a file in parse.com .However,I could not see the  file in the parse cloud after executing my code.Below posted is my java code.However,It worked well when i tried with "ParseObject".Any Suggestions would be helpful

```
public class ToDoList extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "xx", "xx");
    byte[] input = ("\\src\\main\\java\\filename.txt").getBytes();
    ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("Input_data.txt",input);
    parseFile.saveInBackground();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

   }
```

}

Below posted is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/rishik"
    android:label="Rishii"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
<application
        android:name=".ToDoList"
        android:icon="@drawable/rishik"
        android:label="Parse"
        android:allowBackup="true">
    </application>
    <application
        android:name=".file_updated"
        android:icon="@drawable/rishik"
        android:label="gap"
        android:allowBackup="true">
    </application>
   <activity
        android:name=".Main_activity"
        android:label="@string/LOGIN" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ToDoList"
        android:label="@string/LOGIN" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".file_updated"
        android:label="@string/LOGIN" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".first_class" />
    <activity android:name=".rishi" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code and see what the response is sent from parse

```
myfile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
public void done(ParseException e) {
if (e == null) {
    myObjectSavedSuccessfully();
} else {
   Log.d("Error",e.toString())
}
}
});
```

If it is successful you should store the pointer of file in parse object and save it and then you will be able to point to that file from the object and see it in object viewer on parse

Comment: so my Question is do we need to bind  ParseFile to Parse Object inorder to save it in cloud

Comment: The other way is to get the url from the saved file  by using file.geturl() after your file is saved. But I'm not sure about this storage as file might get deleted when you select clean up files in parse. So to be sure that file will be there,it's best to bind it with an object.